# Graph API Schema Extensions not available for user dynamic group filters

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Azure AD Graph Complex Schema Extensions not available for user dynamic group filters

[image: Snapshot]

I am migrating On-Premise AD users to azure AD and created the necessary Graph Schema Extensions (Custom User Attributes) for them accordingly, all fine till now. 
but when trying to use those Extensions as Dynamic group filter; they are not visible in Dynamic groups membership rules.

Looks like only "Active Directory Extension Attributes" are the ones supported dynamic groups filters?

or is there anyway to workaround that (through sync jobs or similar)

I expect the extensions to be listed in dynamic group filter but seems like only Active directory Extensions are available for use in that listing.